# How can I log fatal errors in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling, logging, fatal-error

How can I log the following error to a text file or database?

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PROJECTS::ssss()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is **not possible** to handle fatal errors using a custom error handler.

The best solution is simply enabling error logging (e.g. to syslog) in your php.ini and then using a tool like logcheck/logsentry to receive regular emails about unusual syslog entries.
Instead of syslog PHP can also log errors to a file - simply have a look at the error logging options of php.ini.

```
log_errors = On
error_log = syslog
error_log = /path/to/some/folder/phperrors.log
```

Obviously you only want to use one of the `error_log` lines.

Comment: You should be able to handle a fatal error with register_shutdown_function()

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli: There is no clean way to detect if there was an error in that function.

Comment: `<?php function cleanup(){ print_r(error_get_last()); }` `register_shutdown_function("cleanup");asdfasdf();`

Comment: I agree it's not 100% clean, but it's enough for logging the error, I think.

Comment: Re *"It is not possible to handle fatal errors using a custom error handler."*: Did it change with PHP 7 or not?

Answer (score 13):

There is a way to cope with your task and actually you *can* set a custom error handler on *fatal* errors.

You can do it this way:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
function fatal_handler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    // Do whatever you want with this error. For example:
    YourDBApplicationLayer::writeFatal($error);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Now in PHP 7 it is **possible** to catch fatal errors:

```
try {
    
    ggggg(); // <---- make a fatal error
    
} catch(Throwable $e) {
    
    var_dump($e);
    
}
```

Comment: In PHP 7 there's a new and very useful `Throwable` class, which finally uniforms errors and exceptions, but to implement it you must typecast the error/exception object to Throwable: `try { ggggg(); } catch(\Throwable $e) { var_dump($e); }`

Answer (score 1):

You could have all your <strike>base</strike> *classes* belong to a super-class utilizing [method overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php):

```
class Base 
{
    public function __call($name)
    {
        MyLog::logError(...);
        trigger_error("Function ".get_class($this)."::$name doesn't exist", 
            E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Attempts to invoke non-existing methods of classes derived from `Base` would be ultimately handled by `Base::__call()`. For static methods, accordingly, there's `__callStatic()` (as of PHP 5.3).

Comment: What does the strikeout for "base" mean? Is it an old revision? - can it be deleted? Or something else?

Comment: _"All your base."_ Get it?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
if(!method_exists($obj, 'method')){

   $db->log('What you want to log'); //log in your DB
   error_log('message');//Write to php's error log

}
```

Comment: I have an error handler to handling my error but some error like above, I could not handle them or log.

Comment: Ugh, i'm pretty sure he wants a generic solution.

Comment: I do not know where this error happen. i need to log all type error

Comment: this answer dose not help me because i dont know where or when this error happen